# Stereoscopy support on Linux, software and drivers

Tags: linux, 3d, nvidia, stereoscopy

I would like to know how's the support for stereoscopic on Linux nowadays, for things like Videos (web/local), photos(not as important) and also stereo webcams, is there a driver/software for it?

I have a dedicated nvidia 580m (this one would use the 3d...) and an Intel graphics...

I've found something about Bino3d for video player, and Geeqie for photos, didn't use them yet but i haven't found anything for webcams yet...